# Replacing question marks with guessed letters in Java using arrays

Tags: java, regex

The premise of my project it to create a Hangman kind of game where the user inputs a phrase that contains just letters and spaces, it prints out the phrase but with question marks in place of the letters, and then a second user guesses letters that may be in the phrase. The only part I'm struggling with is getting the guessed letters to replace the question marks again. Right now if you guess any correct letter the entire phrase is revealed. Here is my update method. Any feedback is appreciated!

```
  public static int updateTemplateArray(char [] tmpArr, String sPhrase, char guess)
  {
    int vowel = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < sPhrase.length(); i++)
    {
        if(guess == sPhrase.charAt(i))
        {
            guess = tmpArr[i];
            if (isVowel(guess))
            {
                vowel++;
            }
        }
    }
    return vowel;
} //end updateTemplateArray
```

EDIT: I think the main problem may reside in a different method, here is that

```
 public static void printTemplateArray(char [] tmpArr)
 {
    char [] qMark = new char[tmpArr.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < tmpArr.length; i++)
    {
        if(tmpArr[i] == ' ')
        {
            qMark[i] = ' ';
        }

        else
        {
            qMark[i] = '?';
        }
    }

    System.out.print(qMark);
}
```

Comment: Could you provide us with a typic input for the function and its expected output?

Comment: Say user 1 input "hello world", it would first output "????? ?????". And then if the second user guessed "o" the output should then be "????o ?o???"

Comment: did you ener the right `String` into sPhrase?

Comment: Yes I did. It's a Scanner input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your

```
guess = tmpArr[i];
```

should be

```
tmpArr[i] = guess;
```

You may also want to remove `System.out.println(tmpArr);` statement from your update method since it probably shouldn't be part of it (especially as part of loop). Invoke it after that method to see results on your array which was represented by `tmpArr`.

Simplified demo:

```
public static void updateTemplateArray(char[] tmpArr, String sPhrase, char guess) {

    for (int i = 0; i < sPhrase.length(); i++) {
        if (guess == sPhrase.charAt(i)) {
            tmpArr[i] = guess;
        }
    }
}

...

String phrase = "foo bar";
char[] arr = new char[phrase.length()];
Arrays.fill(arr, '?');

//guessing time
updateTemplateArray(arr, phrase, 'f');
System.out.println(arr);
updateTemplateArray(arr, phrase, 'b');
System.out.println(arr);
updateTemplateArray(arr, phrase, 'x');
System.out.println(arr);
```

Output:

```
f??????
f???b??
f???b??
```

RE Edit:

In your `printTemplateArray(char [] tmpArr)` method you are simply creating new array which is filled with either space or `?`. So there is no way for it to print other characters that these two.
If you want this method to only hide with `?` characters which are not spaces and ware not guessed by second player then you should store somewhere and pass to your method guesses of that player (`Set<Character>` seems to be right collection for that). So your corrected code could look like:

```
public static void printTemplateArray(char[] tmpArr,
        Set<Character> guesses) {
    char[] qMark = new char[tmpArr.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < tmpArr.length; i++) {
        if (tmpArr[i] == ' ') {
            qMark[i] = ' ';
        } else if (guesses.contains(tmpArr[i])) {
            qMark[i] = tmpArr[i];// copy already guessed char
        } else {
            qMark[i] = '?';
        }
    }

    System.out.print(qMark);
}
```

Comment: Good call, unfortunately it still does the same thing

Comment: I just tried with your demo, it still prints out the original array, no question marks, and I guess that makes sense now that I think about it.

Comment: I suspect that your problem is somewhere outside of method you posted which means I can't help you without seeing example which will let me reproduce it.

Comment: You're right, I think I figured it out now thank you!

Comment: @Dakota I updated my answer. Maybe it will interest you.